# React Typescript: Restricting Props setting with dynamic data

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm new on typescript and I would like to ask a question on passing dynamic data to a React component with restricting props setting.

I have found a simple component, under the limitation of "RandomNumberProps", the component accept either "isPositive", "isNegative", or "isZero"

```
type RandomNumberType = {
  value: number;
};

type PositiveNumber = RandomNumberType & {
  isPositive: boolean;
  isNegative?: never;
  isZero?: never;
};

type NegativeNumber = RandomNumberType & {
  isNegative: boolean;
  isPositive?: never;
  isZero?: never;
};

type Zero = RandomNumberType & {
  isZero: boolean;
  isPositive?: never;
  isNegative?: never;
};

type RandomNumberProps = PositiveNumber | NegativeNumber | Zero;

export const RandomNumber = ({
  value,
  isPositive,
  isNegative,
  isZero,
}: RandomNumberProps) => {
  return (
    <div>
      {value} {isPositive && "positive"} {isNegative && "negative"}{" "}
      {isZero && "zero"}
    </div>
  );
};
```

I can use the component like this:

```
<RandomNumber value={10} isPositive></RandomNumber>
```

Then I try to enhance the component using mock data but I have get a error from typescript

```
const item = {
    value: 0,
    isPositive: false,
    isNegative: false,
    isZero: true,
  };

<RandomNumber
    value={item.value}
    {...item.isPositive && { isPositive: true }}
    {...item.isNegative && { isNegative: true }}
    {...item.isZero && { isZero: true }}
></RandomNumber>
```

Error Message

```
(alias) const RandomNumber: ({ value, isPositive, isNegative, isZero, }: RandomNumberProps) => JSX.Element
import RandomNumber
Type '{ isZero?: true | undefined; isNegative?: true | undefined; isPositive?: true | undefined; value: number; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & RandomNumberProps'.
  Type '{ isZero?: true | undefined; isNegative?: true | undefined; isPositive?: true | undefined; value: number; }' is not assignable to type '{ isZero: boolean; isPositive?: undefined; isNegative?: undefined; }'.
    Types of property 'isZero' are incompatible.
      Type 'boolean | undefined' is not assignable to type 'boolean'.
        Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'boolean'.ts(2322)
```

May i know:

1. What is the cause of the problem and how to resolve it?
2. Is it common to set a dynamic props (isPositive, isNegative, isZero)?
3. What is the scenario to use

- dynamic props (isPositive, isNegative, isZero)
- same props with different value (status: "positive" | "negative" | "zero")

Thanks

---

Working Example

```
type RandomNumberType = {
  value: number;
};

type PositiveNumber = RandomNumberType & {
  isPositive: boolean;
  isNegative?: never;
  isZero?: never;
};

type NegativeNumber = RandomNumberType & {
  isNegative: boolean;
  isPositive?: never;
  isZero?: never;
};

type Zero = RandomNumberType & {
  isZero: boolean;
  isPositive?: never;
  isNegative?: never;
};

type RandomNumberProps = PositiveNumber | NegativeNumber | Zero;

const RandomNumber = ({
  value,
  isPositive,
  isNegative,
  isZero,
}: RandomNumberProps) => {
  return (
    <div>
      {value} {isPositive && "positive"} {isNegative && "negative"}{" "}
      {isZero && "zero"}
    </div>
  );
};

function App() {
  const item = {
    value: 0,
    isPositive: false,
    isNegative: false,
    isZero: true,
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <RandomNumber value={10} isPositive></RandomNumber>
      <RandomNumber
        value={item.value}
        {...(item.isPositive && { isPositive: true })}
        {...(item.isNegative && { isNegative: true })}
        {...(item.isZero && { isZero: true })}
      ></RandomNumber>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: what error do you got?

Comment: @VladimirTrotsenko Thanks for reminder, i have updated the question with error message.

Comment: Can you post a working example in the Playground with the error?

Comment: hi @beautifulcoder, I have added the working example to the question, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've worked around your question, tell me if it is helpful.
First, changed a bit of types. Used interface but it is the same as type and &. Also, I think it is better to have boolean for positive and negative at the same time because they cannot be both true or false.

```
type RandomNumberType = {
    value: number;
};

interface PositiveNegativeNumber extends RandomNumberType {
    isPositive: boolean;
    isZero: false;
};

interface Zero extends RandomNumberType {
    isPositive: false;
    isZero: boolean;
};

type RandomNumberProps = PositiveNegativeNumber | Zero;
```

Next, just putting one prop item that is of type `RandomNumberProps`

```
const RandomNumber:FC<{item: RandomNumberProps}> = ({ item }) => {
    return (
        <div>
            {item.value} {item.isPositive && "positive"} {!item.isPositive && !item.isZero && "negative"} {" "}
            {item.isZero && "zero"}
        </div>
    );
};
```

Lastly, I put your variable in the state in order to dynamically change it.

```
function App() {
    const [item, setItem] = useState<RandomNumberProps>({
        value: 0,
        isPositive: false,
        isZero: true
    })

    return (
        <div className="App">
            <RandomNumber item={item}></RandomNumber>
            <button onClick={() => setItem({...item, value: 2, isPositive: true, isZero: false})}>Positive</button>
            <button onClick={() => setItem({...item, value: -2, isPositive: false, isZero: false})}>Negative</button>
            <button onClick={() => setItem({...item, value: 0, isPositive: false, isZero: true})}>Zero</button>
        </div>
    );
}
```

So, you can pass your value with two properties `isPositive` and `isZero` and it will render accordingly.